# Vincular duas classes

Tags: java

Olá, pessoal!

Estou desenvolvendo um trabalho da faculdade que é um mini sistema bancário com Java SE e estou usando Swing pra interface. Tenho um pouco de dificuldade com o paradigma OO e queria saber como eu faço pra relacionar uma classe cliente com uma classe conta. No banco, eu usei `foreign key` para relacionar minha `table cliente` com a `table conta`. Mas nas classes Java? como faço pra associar uma conta nova a um cliente já existente? Já testei meu crud de cliente e está funcionando.
Esta é minha classe cliente:

```
package modelo;

public class Cliente {
Conta conta;
private int id;
private String nome;
private String sobrenome;
private String cpf;
private String rg;
private String endereco;



public Cliente(String nome, String sobrenome, String cpf,
        String rg, String endereco) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    this.cpf = cpf;
    this.rg = rg;
    this.endereco = endereco;
}



public int getId() {
    return id;
}



public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}



public Cliente(){
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getSobrenome() {
    return sobrenome;
}
public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
    this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
}
public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}
public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}
public String getRg() {
    return rg;
}
public void setRg(String rg) {
    this.rg = rg;
}
public String getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}
public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}




}
```

E esse é o meu `clienteDAO`:

```
package dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import conexao.ConnectionFactory;
import modelo.Cliente;
import dao.ClienteDAO;

public class ClienteDAO {
Connection con;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs;

public void cadastraCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO cliente (nome, sobrenome, rg, cpf, endereco)" +
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        ps.setString(1, cliente.getNome());
        ps.setString(2, cliente.getSobrenome());
        ps.setString(3, cliente.getRg());
        ps.setString(4, cliente.getCpf());
        ps.setString(5, cliente.getEndereco());

        PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT idCliente FROM cliente WHERE nome LIKE '?' AND sobrenome "
            +   "LIKE '?' AND rg LIKE '?' AND cpf LIKE '?' AND  endereco LIKE '?'");
        ps2.setString(1, cliente.getNome());
        ps2.setString(2, cliente.getSobrenome());
        ps2.setString(3, cliente.getRg());
        ps2.setString(4, cliente.getCpf());
        ps2.setString(5, cliente.getEndereco());
        rs = ps2.executeQuery();
        cliente.setId(rs.getInt("idCliente"));

        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public Cliente buscaCliente(String busca){
    con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE nome LIKE '%?%' OR sobrenome "
            +   "LIKE '%?%' OR rg LIKE '%?%' OR cpf LIKE '%?%' OR  endereco LIKE '%?%'");
        ps.setString(1, busca);
        ps.setString(2, busca);
        ps.setString(3, busca);
        ps.setString(4, busca);
        ps.setString(5, busca);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
            cliente.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            cliente.setSobrenome(rs.getString("sobrenome"));
            cliente.setRg(rs.getString("rg"));
            cliente.setCpf(rs.getString("cpf"));
            cliente.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
        con.close();
        return cliente;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public List<Cliente> listaClientes() {
    List<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM cliente");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        while(rs.next()){
            cliente.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            cliente.setSobrenome(rs.getString("sobrenome"));
            cliente.setRg(rs.getString("rg"));
            cliente.setCpf(rs.getString("cpf"));
            cliente.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
            clientes.add(cliente);
        }
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return clientes;
}

public void atualizaDados(Cliente cliente, int id) {
    con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE banco.cliente SET nome = ?, sobrenome = ?, rg = ?, cpf =?, endereco = ? where idCliente = ?");
        ps.setString(1, cliente.getNome());
        ps.setString(2, cliente.getSobrenome());
        ps.setString(3, cliente.getRg());
        ps.setString(4, cliente.getCpf());
        ps.setString(5, cliente.getEndereco());
        ps.setInt(6, id);

        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void excluiCliente(String nome) {
    con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM cliente WHERE nome = ?");
        ps.setString(1, nome);

        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public List<Cliente> ordenaLista(String coluna) {
    List<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM cliente ORDER BY ?");
        ps.setString(1, coluna);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        while(rs.next()){
            cliente.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            cliente.setSobrenome(rs.getString("sobrenome"));
            cliente.setRg(rs.getString("rg"));
            cliente.setCpf(rs.getString("cpf"));
            cliente.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
            clientes.add(cliente);
        }
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return clientes;
}

public List<String> populaCombo(){
    List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT nome FROM cliente");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            nomes.add(rs.getString("nome"));
        }
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
        con.close();
        return nomes;           
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}


}
```

Eu criei uma `classe ContaCorrente` e uma `ContaInvestimento` que herdam de Conta e implementam uma `interface ContaI`. Essa é a `ContaCorrente`:

```
package modelo;

public class ContaCorrente extends Conta {
double limite;

public ContaCorrente(){

}



public ContaCorrente(double saldo, double limite) {
    this.saldo = saldo;
    this.limite = limite;
}



public double getLimite() {
    return limite;
}

public void setLimite(double limite) {
    this.limite = limite;
}

@Override
public boolean deposita(double valor) {
    return super.deposita(valor);
}

@Override
public boolean saca(double valor) {
    if(valor > this.saldo + limite){
        System.out.println("Você não tem saldo suficiente para realizar esse saque");
    }
    System.out.println("Saque realizado com sucesso");
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cliente getDono() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getNumero() {
    return this.numero;
}

@Override
public double getSaldo() {
    return this.saldo;
}

@Override
public void remunera() {
    this.saldo *= 0.01;
}

}
```

E essa é a `ContaInvestimento`:

```
package modelo;

public class ContaInvestimento extends Conta{
double montanteMinimo;
double depositoMinimo;

public ContaInvestimento(){

}



public ContaInvestimento(double saldo, double montanteMinimo, double depositoMinimo) {
    this.saldo = saldo;
    this.montanteMinimo = montanteMinimo;
    this.depositoMinimo = depositoMinimo;
}



@Override
public boolean deposita(double valor) {
    if(valor >= depositoMinimo){
        super.deposita(valor);
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean saca(double valor) {
    return super.deposita(valor);
}
@Override
public Cliente getDono() {
    return null;
}
@Override
public int getNumero() {
    return this.numero;
}
@Override
public double getSaldo() {
    return this.saldo;
}
@Override
public void remunera() {
    this.saldo *= 0.01;
}
}
```

Mas eu fiz um único `contaDAO` para as duas `classes`:

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import conexao.ConnectionFactory;
import modelo.Cliente;
import modelo.ContaCorrente;
import modelo.ContaInvestimento;

public class ContaDAO {
Connection con;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs;

public void criaContaCorrente(ContaCorrente conta){
    con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO conta (saldo) VALUES (?)");
        ps.setDouble(1, conta.getSaldo() + conta.getLimite());

        PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT idConta FROM conta WHERE idCliente = ?");
            ps.setInt(1,conta.getDono().getId());
            rs = ps2.executeQuery();
            conta.setNumero(rs.getInt("idConta"));

        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void criaContaInvestimento(ContaInvestimento conta){
    con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO banco.conta (saldo) VALUES (?)");
        ps.setDouble(1, conta.getSaldo());

        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean atualizaSaldo(double valor, int numero) {
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE conta SET saldo = ? WHERE idConta = ?");
            ps.setDouble(1, valor);
            ps.setInt(2, numero);
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public Cliente getDono() {
    return null;
}

public double getSaldo(int numero) {
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT saldo WHERE idConta = ?");
            ps.setInt(1, numero);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            double saldo = rs.getDouble("saldo");
            return saldo;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Na minha classe `VincularConta` eu tenho o seguinte `actionPerformed`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(tipoConta.getSelectedItem().equals("Conta Corrente")){
        ContaDAO cd = new ContaDAO();
        ContaCorrente conta = new ContaCorrente(Double.parseDouble(depositoInicial.getText()),
                Double.parseDouble(limite.getText()));
        cd.criaContaCorrente(conta);
    }
    if(tipoConta.getSelectedItem().equals("Conta Investimento")){
        ContaDAO cd = new ContaDAO();
        ContaInvestimento conta = new ContaInvestimento(Double.parseDouble(depositoInicial2.getText()),
                Double.parseDouble(depositoMinimo.getText()), Double.parseDouble(montanteMinimoInput.getText()) );
        cd.criaContaInvestimento(conta);
    }
}
```

No meu `ClienteDAO` eu tento pegar o id do cliente gerado pelo bd e no meu `ContaDAO` eu tento usar o id que peguei do cliente pra pegar o id da conta. Mas não estou conseguindo nem criar a conta, muito menos pegar o id. Podem me ajudar a entender o que tem de errado no meu CRUD? Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 1):

Para poder criar qualquer conta que seja, como você tem uma `foreign-key` de cliente dentro de conta, é necessário primeiro criar o cliente, ter o **Id** do cliente, para por fim você cadastrar a conta.

É muito interessante o que você esta fazendo, eu posso aconselhar algumas coisas mas vai depender muito das regras de negócio do seu software para que você consiga atingir um bom requisito implementado.

Primeiramente, na classe `Conta`, que é *super-classe* de todas as demais contas, você deve criar um objeto de de cliente como atributo da classe. Dessa forma, a partir de uma conta, você pode saber qual é o cliente.

Qualquer inserção no banco de conta que você realizar seguirá essa ordem:

- Tenha um objeto de cliente, seja ele existente (no banco) ou não.
- Se for existente, não é necessário chamar o DAO de cliente, já que esse cliente já tem um **Id** *setado*
- Se não for existente, é necessário primeiramente incluir este cliente no banco e gerar o **Id** dele.
- Por fim, tendo sempre um cliente com **Id** *setado*, basta você *setar* esse cliente no objeto de Conta, (`conta.setCliente(cliente);` seja ela corrente, ou *whatever*. Lembre-se que ao criar um atributo cliente na *super-classe* Conta, todas as demais contas herdarão esse atributo.
- Execute o DAO de conta, no campo **Id** do cliente, você já terá referenciado o **Id** do cliente existente.

Ficaria algo como:

```
public abstract Conta {
//...
private Cliente cliente; //atributo de cliente em conta
//getters and setters
}
```

O mais interessante dessa abordagem, que essa é a unica associação que você precisa para poder deixar sua aplicação funcionando.

Digamos por exemplo que você queria buscar quais são as contas que um determinado cliente possui.

Você deve fazer um select na tabela de contas buscando pelas contas que tem no campo Id_cliente, o Id do cliente que você procura.

Você sempre vai retornar zero, uma ou várias contas que tem aquele cliente como Id_cliente. Assim não é necessário, por exemplo, criar qualquer outra associação de conta com cliente (Como por exemplo, criar um atributo Lista de contas dentro da classe de cliente)

Espero que você tenha entendido o conceito. Para qualquer dúvida, estou a disposição.